# geth inter-node communication (devp2p/rlpx) encryption

Tags: encryption, devp2p, rlp, rlpx

I am currently analysing the encryption mechanisms used in geth.

Currently I have gathered the following information from the source code (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/rlpx.go):

- communication is encrypted
- no server certificate / CA chains like in TLS
- Key Exchange via: ECDSA / secp256k1
- ECDSA publicKeyLength: 256-bit
- SharedSecretKeyLength: 16-byte

Is this correct so far?

Does someone know if there is any documentation on encryption in the inter-node protocol?

**Update**
From https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md (thanks Richard Horrocks for pointing to it):

> The RLPx handshake is considered 'broken crypto' because aes-secret and mac-secret are reused for both reading and writing. The two sides of a RLPx connection generate two CTR streams from the same key, nonce and IV. If an attacker knows one plaintext, they can decrypt unknown plaintexts of the reused keystream.

**Update** Asked at crypto.stackexchange.com about the encryption flaw above -> https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63047/ethereum-rlpx-protocol-for-inter-node-communication-flaws-in-the-encryption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does someone know if there is any documentation on encryption in the inter-node protocol?

You might have already found these, but here are few sources I've used in the past:

- https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md (The RLPx Transport Protocol)
- https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/devp2p.md (devp2p Application Protocol)

Gitter channel: https://gitter.im/ethereum/devp2p

Consensys's Wireshark dissectors for devp2p: https://github.com/ConsenSys/ethereum-dissectors